# Multiple jQuery UI Tooltips

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, d3.js, tooltip

I used d3.js to create a zoomable tree map of the commodities market, which works great, but now I'm trying to show a jQuery UI tooltip on each mouse enter of the cell and then hide (or destroy or close) that tooltip on mouse exit and show another (or the same tooltip because I only want one tooltip displayed at a time). The code I wrote works as intended in Chrome and Mozilla (see image below), 
[image: Mozilla and Chrome Experience]

but when I test in IE 11 the tooltips remain and don't disappear on mouse exit (see image below).
[image: IE 11 Experience]

```
chart.selectAll("g.cell.child")
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .on("mouseenter", function (d) {
    showToolTip(d, this);
  });

function showToolTip (d, t) {
   var htmlMarkup = ""; // Create some HTML to place in tooltip
   $(t).tooltip({ items: t, content: htmlMarkup, close: function (event, ui) {
   }, open: function (event, ui) {
   }});
}
```

I'm not sure if creating the tooltip on the fly is the best approach, but since it works most of the time and fast I assumed it was fine until I saw it not work in IE. What's the best approach for creating one tooltip and then just moving it around and changing it's content when needed?

Answer (score 0):

After scouring the web, I was able to find a solution to this with the below code:

```
$(".ui-tooltip").remove();
```

It may not be the best approach, but it works on IE and Chrome.